# Oldest photographed mathematician

Tags: ho.history-overview

Who is the most ancient mathematician of which we have a photograph? 
(or, in the same vein, what is the oldest photograph of a mathematician) 
A quick search on MacTutor History of Mathematics gives Binet (b.1786) as a pretender with Cauchy (b.1789) coming close...

Comment: This is a fairly arbitrary question of little research interest, but I imagine it is of some interest to the audience here.  The word "photo" gets used somewhat flexibly in English so you might want to specify if you mean "likeness recorded on photographic paper via an early camera" or something more flexible, like "likeness recorded in a painting or sketch" or the most flexible "likeness recorded by an artist that imagined what the person looked like".

Comment: I believe that photograph is more suitable than _portrait_ or _picture_ which are more vague. Photograph seems to be the most adequate term for a light generated representation.

Comment: you can ask your question here http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But I believe that there are more mathematicians with some interesest in photography than vice-versa.

Comment: At least as far as videos go, there are some old mathematicians here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7Kz_Le7BOc

Around the 33 minute mark you can see David Hilbert shoveling snow.

Comment: This is a wrong site for such questions. Try History of Math and Sciences. They like to discuss such questions:-)

Comment: I personally find the question quite interesting to appear on this site.

Comment: I agree that the question does not pertain to research _per se_ however, I believe that this is the most appropriate place to ask this meta-question. I believe that asking about e.g. the history of the notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not more germane than the above.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Most ancient: Wikipedia has a [daguerreotype of Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) (1777–1855) on his deathbed. Or possibly [Farkas Bolyai](https://archive.org/stream/jstor-2968693#page/n2) (1775–1856) in what look like similar circumstances.

Less ancient, but allegedly photographed earlier: Googling "daguerreotype mathematician" gives

• c. [1840](https://www.gettyimages.com/license/50799253), [1840](https://www.gettyimages.com/license/50799251): Augustus De Morgan (1806–1871)
• c. [1842–1843](http://www.claymath.org/publications/ada-lovelaces-mathematical-papers): Ada Lovelace (1815–1852)
• c. [1843](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Friedrich_Wilhelm_Bessel_1843_B.jpg): Friedrich Wilhelm Bessel (1784–1846)
• c. [1843](http://www.mhsgent.ugent.be/engl-plat12.html): Joseph Plateau (1801–1883)
• c. [1843](https://www.gettyimages.com/license/90732052), [1847–1851](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Charles_Babbage_by_Antoine_Claudet_c1847-51-crop.jpg): Charles Babbage (1791–1871)
• c. [1844](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:W_H_F_Talbot.jpg): William Henry Fox Talbot (1800–1877)
• c. [1845](https://www.gettyimages.com/license/90772948): François Arago (1786–1853)
• c. [1845](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/BigPictures/Hamilton_2.jpeg): William Rowan Hamilton (1805–1865) (per [frontispiece](//zbmath.org/?q=an:57.0034.09))
• c. [1846](//en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Popular_Science_Monthly_Volume_72.djvu/191): William Thomson (1824–1907)
• c. [1846](https://www.gettyimages.com/license/463906191): John Couch Adams (1819–1892)
• c. [1847](https://www.gettyimages.com/license/2641935): Hermann von Helmholtz (1821–1894)
• c. [1848](https://www.npg.org.uk/collections/search/portrait/mw09661/Sir-John-Frederick-William-Herschel-1st-Bt): John Herschel (1792–1871).

Comment: Wait a minute, how do Binet and Cauchy fit into this chronology?

Comment: According to wikipedia (fr), Cauchy's picture was taken soon before his death (1857). Isn't Binet a psychologist?

Comment: There's more than one Binet.  The relevant one here must be
Jacques Philippe Marie Binet (1876-1856), as in the Cauchy-Binet formula for
$\det(AB)$, not Alfred Binet (1857-1911) as in the Stanford-Binet
intelligence scales.

Comment: Typo alert – Binet did not die $20$ years before he was born.

Comment: The link for Joseph Plateau seems to be dead, but there are some versions [archived in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20070623162611/http://www.mhsgent.ugent.be/engl-plat12.html).